# How to use Shift() with Apply() function to iterate over rows?

Tags: python, pandas, apply, shift

For a stock price dataframe with Date as index, when I use shift() to get previous value and use apply() to create a column storing the previous value, it gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'shift'
```

Following is the code that generates this error:

```
df.head(10)
             Open   High    Low  Close    Volume
Date                                            
2004-01-01  66.60  71.55  66.70  71.55  664600.0
2004-01-02  71.55  76.85  73.55  74.50  608500.0
2004-01-05  74.50  77.00  73.50  73.50  249400.0
2004-01-06  73.50  74.45  72.30  73.30  248600.0
2004-01-07  73.30  74.75  72.95  73.50   98600.0
2004-01-08  73.50  74.25  72.00  72.60   97000.0
2004-01-09  72.60  73.50  72.05  72.80   66900.0
2004-01-12  72.80  74.10  72.65  72.65   75100.0
2004-01-13  72.65  73.50  71.55  72.50   80500.0
2004-01-14  72.50  72.75  68.90  68.90  176100.0
```

2. We create a function and then use apply to create the column:

```
def momentum(df):

    df['Pre_Close'] = df['Close'].shift(-1)

df['Pre_Close']= df.apply( lambda df: momentum(df), axis=1)
```

Question: Please help in resolving this error. (Note): I have skipped a lot of code to keep the function simple)

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'shift'
```

Comment: Do you mean `df['Pre_Close']= df['Close'].shift(-1)` ?

Comment: What is the need for the lambda function and the function? Just `df['Pre_Close'] = df['Close'].shift(-1)` will do.

Comment: `df['Pre_Close'] = df[['Close']].shift(-1)` try this out

Comment: @NYCCoder : Yes, if it was simple one liner code. this was enough. But i have extracted a line that creating  problem from a larger complex function which is part of the loop in Momentum function. Only this line is creating problem so trouble shooting it. Will be grateful for your help.

Comment: @AndrejKesely : Yes, brother.

Comment: @baqarjafri I don't know specifics of your problem, but you can do `df['Pre_Close']= df['Close'].shift(-1)` and then access `Pre_Close` in your lambda function.

Comment: @AndrejKesely : How can I run this code by modifying the line `df['Pre_Close']= df['Close'].shift(-1)` in the function itself. Would be grateful for you help.

Comment: @Vaebhav Thank you so much. The code is functioning. To educate, please share how converting into data frame column  has worked. Although I am still trying to figure out how it will work in the larger code block. It will still be helpful to know the logic. Thank you!

Comment: @baqarjafri - Happy to help, if you like the answer do accept it as well :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason the below snippet works , is enclosing a single column within an extra square brackets return a `DataFrame`

```
df['Pre_Close'] = df[['Close']].shift(-1) 

df[['Column Name']] -----> returns a DataFrame
df['Column Name'] -----> returns a Series
```

Also regarding the objective of fetching the previous values based out of a column `shift` is the easiest way to use , and serves the purpose right

Else a more programatic approach would be as below

Since each column values are `list/numpy array` in the lowest essence

The below function is very trivial and only would work in a 1-D dimensional input

```
def shift_vector(inp,shift):

    if isinstance(inp,list):
       n = len(inp)
       first_half = [0] * shift
       return return first_half + inp[shift:]
    elif isinstance(inp,numpy.ndarray):
       n = len(inp)
       first_half = np.zeros(1,shift)
       return numpy.concatenate([first_half,inp[shift:])
```

The idea is to demonstrate on a very trivial level how shifting can be achieved using indexes

Comment: @Vaehav: The code did not produce any error but the functionality is still not working. For this function: `def momentum(df):
    
    if (
       (df['_close_positive'] == 1.0) & \
       (df[['Call']].shift(1).values != 100.0) 
        ):
         return 100.0
    else:
         return 0.0`

When we populate the "Call" column through this line:

`df['Call']= df.apply(lambda df: momentum(df), axis=1)`  The function does not check if the previous value of column was 100 or not . In essence, it does check the shift() command if if else statement.

Comment: please refer to above comment.